# Adding additional commands to angular options list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select, ng-options

What is the simplest way to add some commands to the end of the Angular select box?
E.g. I want to get a list like this:

1. Cat
2. Dog
3. Octopus
4. Browse…

All items except Browse are some data / `ng-options`, but Browse is a command and always present. It should not be actually selectable as an item, and should call a handler instead.

I suppose I could put this command into the list bound to `ng-options` and manage it as a special case, but that feels like a hack. Is there a proper approach to this?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly at the time of selecting the `Browse` option

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan a callback with some custom code (dialog, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this, here when you select the browse it will open a dialog box

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nidhishkrishnan/zx9uh1op/5/)**

**html**

```
<form ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-init="item = this">
    <select ng-model="animal"  ng-change="clickToOpen()" ng-init="animal='select'">
    <option value="select">Please select an animal</option>
    <option ng-repeat="animal in animalsGroup">{{animal.name}}
    </option>
    <option value="Browse..">Browse..</option>
</select>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId">
    <h1>Template heading</h1>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <center><input type="button" value="OK" ng-click="closeThisDialog(this)"/></center>
</script>
</form>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngDialog']);

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, ngDialog) {

 $scope.animalsGroup = [
          {name:'Cat'},
          {name:'Dog'},
          {name:'Octopus'}
         ];    

 // select initial value
 $scope.animal = $scope.animalsGroup[0];
 //

 $scope.clickToOpen = function () {
     if ($scope.animal === 'Browse..')
     {
         $scope.animal = "select";
         ngDialog.open({
            template: 'templateId',
            className: 'ngdialog-theme-plain',
            showClose: false,
        });
     }
     else
     {
         // other than 'Browse'
     }
 }; 

 $scope.closeThisDialog = function (dialog) {
    dialog.close(); 
 }
});
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I considered this approach. But I wonder whether it is possible to do that without adding Browse to the controller data. Browse is a command, not really a data, so I would expect to have it only as a method on the controller.

So far it seems a custom directive is required.

I'll wait a bit to see if anyone has a different proposal, then accept this one if no one does.

Comment: actually you can achieve that like as given in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nidhishkrishnan/btrkou9r/4/), but instead of `ng-option` i used `ng-repeat`

Comment: That fiddle is really good, but how do I select an initial value (and eliminate empty entry)? See http://jsfiddle.net/zx9uh1op/1/ -- first item is not selected.

Comment: Thanks! I actually want to select the first one (e.g. Cat), not the empty one, but I'll ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Can you update you answer with `ng-repeat` instead of `ng-option`?

Comment: if you want to use `ng-option` then the Browse will be at the top

Comment: No, `ng-repeat` is the right one, I am just saying your answer still has `ng-options`.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood corectly you want to handle the browse option differently .

**Script :**

```
   $scope.colors = [
          {name:'Cat'},
          {name:'Dog'},
          {name:'Octopus'},
          {name:'Browse'}
        ];
    $scope.handleChange = function(){
    if ($scope.myColor.name === 'Browse'){
    // your implementation 

    }

    }
```

**Html :**

```
<select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors" ng-change="handleChange"></select>
```

Comment: I considered that, but do I have to put "Browse" into the `colors`?
It is not really a color.

Comment: Yeah that is one of angular way to keep the dom clean and write business in script